# get active item in a card layout

Tags: extjs4, sencha-architect

is there a way to get the active item of a card layout panel?

I used to use it until the last update [ today ]. after update it just stopped !!

is there any other way to check which panel/card is activated ?

Comment: You need to report a bug if it just stopped working without any code changes. You're using the `panel.getActiveItem()` method right?

Comment: yes.. `Ext.getCmp('panel id').getLayout().getActiveItem()`

Comment: .getLayout() becouse I am in panel with card layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`panel.getLayout().getActiveItem()` is the method to use.

Here's the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Card-method-getActiveItem)

That is the recommended method. You don't need to look for alternatives.

Comment: i got this error: `Object [object Object] has no method 'getActiveItem' `

Comment: Your layout is being overriden somewhere. Check the layout property of the panel in firebug. What is the `object` that you're getting in the error? It will be a subclass of `Ext.layout.Layout`